# WSO2 ESB with x-www-form-urlencoded messaage type service call

Tags: rest, soap, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have used following code for sending x-www-form-urlencoded message to backed server.

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="FormDataReceiver">
   <http uri-template="http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessageEndpoint.html" method="post">
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
   </http>
</endpoint>
```

Also used following API code.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="FORM" context="/Service">
   <resource methods="POST">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"></log>
         <property name="name" value="Mark" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
         <property name="company" value="wso2" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
         <property name="country" value="US" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                  <soapenv:Body>
                     <root xmlns="">
                        <name>$1</name>
                        <company>$2</company>
                        <country>$3</country>
                     </root>
                  </soapenv:Body>
               </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:name"></arg>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:company"></arg>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:country"></arg>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full"></log>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
         <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
         <call>
            <endpoint key="FormDataReceiver"></endpoint>
         </call>
         <respond></respond>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

But still that message send as rest call manner.

I want something like following message body into backed server. This example message should send through the message body. In here I have used WSO2 Given Example. I have added same wso2esb link for your further reference. [wso2](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Configuring+Specific+Use+Cases). Actually I need to send message XML={{my_xml_message_here}}. Please help me to continue this. Thanks lot.

```
name=Mark&company=wso2
```

Comment: What is the version of ESB you're using? 4.8.1? Also, what is the exact payload going out from ESB?

Comment: ESB version is wso2ei-6.4.0

Answer (score 0):

There is missing `Content-Type` in header for this type of request. Need to add:

```
<header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
```